# select in dropdownlist a value, without id

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu

i want to select the 3rd value (Moon)
the html

```
    <select name="planettype" onChange="updateVars()" onKeyUp="updateVars()">
                    <option value="1" selected="selected">Planet</option>
<option value="2">Debris Field</option>
<option value="3">Moon</option>

                    </select>
```

i tested:

void(document.getElementsByTagName("planettype").text = 'Moon');
void(document.getElementsByTagName("planettype").value = '3');

- not working

i can not even "access" the dropdown list, there is a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use something like:

```
document.getElementsByName("planettype")[0].options[2].selected = true;
```

`planettype` isn't a tag name - it's a name. You want the moon option which is third, and then set selected as true.

Answer (score 2):

get the select, and set the `selectedIndex` property :

```
document.getElementsByName('planettype')[0].selectedIndex = 2;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/aqmnG/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the selectedIndex property

document.getElementByName("planettype").selectedIndex = 3;

Comment: dont work, palnettype is not a ID!

look first and second answers!!

Comment: oh it should be getElementByName

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this:

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("option")[2].text;
alert(v)
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/U2rZN/15/**

Avoid using function Names within markup, You can also try something like this in jQUery

```
$(function() {
    $("select option").click(function() {
      alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/U2rZN/25/**